# SSRS format to 1 decimal place

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to display in the first column the label with the average of the day value. But I would like to display the average with decimal place.
How can I format this expression to 1 decimal place?

```
Fields!Label.Value & "[" & Avg(Fields!Scrap.Value) & "]"
```

**Solution**

```
 =Fields!Label.Value & "[" & Format(Avg(Fields!Scrap.Value),"N1") & "%]"
```

Comment: Format the textbox as n1

Comment: ok thanks taht was really easy

Comment: Always remember it's easier to format the textbox than in the background.

Answer (score 0):

In the top designer bar in the number field, change it from Default to Number. Then use the little decimal buttons to adjust how many decimals you will allow.

I don't have enough rep to post images, but screen shot link below.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOmFF.png)